# Error AbstractMethodError when I create a CriteriaQuery

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am migrating from hibernate 4 to hibernate 5 I have a problem since several days when I believe that a criterion and execution and the list method () I skipped the following error.

For the mistake I think it's something from nullSafeGet and update the nullSafeGet and nullSafeSet methods, but I have not had success.

this is the code

```
        CriteriaQuery<RepresentantePartido> query =
            criteria.createQuery(Represent.class);
        Root<Represent> entity = query.from(Represent.class);

        List<Predicate> condiciones = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

        if (Util.notNullMayorCero(procesoId)) {
            condiciones.add(criteria.equal(entity.get("proceso.id"), procesoId));

        }

        query.select(entity);
        query.where(condiciones.toArray(new Predicate[] {}));


        Query<Represent> consulta = getCurrentSession().createQuery(query);

        if (Util.notNullMayorCero(pagina) && Util.notNullMayorCero(filas)) {
            consulta.setFirstResult(filas * (pagina - 1)).setMaxResults(filas);

        }

        return consulta.list();
```

this is error

```
 java.lang.AbstractMethodError
        at org.hibernate.type.CustomType.nullSafeGet(CustomType.java:119)
        at org.hibernate.type.AbstractType.hydrate(AbstractType.java:91)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3014)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1750)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1676)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1565)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:730)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:989)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:947)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:339)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2693)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2676)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2510)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2505)
        at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:504)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:396)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:219)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1537)
        at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1561)
        at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1529)
        at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.list(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:96)
```

I hope you can help me.

Comment: if you'd supplied the code that triggers this exception that would be great!

Comment: You are using a `CustomType` which isn't compatible with the  version of Hibernate you are currently using.

Comment: I am using the Custom Type that come in the jar of hibernate core 5.4.3